# Translating WordPress: Which naming convention should I use when defining the language?

Tags: wordpress, internationalization

My aim is to change a number of text strings used in WordPress. So far, I've downloaded the official [WordPress .pot file](http://svn.automattic.com/wordpress-i18n/pot/trunk/wordpress.pot) and saved it under wp-content/lanuages/wordpress.pot. I have a copy of [Poedit](http://www.poedit.net/) and am ready to start editing.

In config.php I am not sure whether to have `define('WPLANG', 'en');` or `define('WPLANG', 'en_US');`. My website visitors come from various English speaking countries such as the UK and the United States. Should I use a non-specific naming convention such as `en` or must I add a country code e.g. `en_US`?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress

Comment: it will work with any name #(e.g. xx_XX ) but may I ask what it the final goal of this ?? there must be a better way ..

Comment: My aim is to change a number of text strings used in WordPress

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I came across the answer in http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_in_Your_Language

> Download the .mo language file for your language (see WordPress in
>   Your Language for hints on how to find one). The naming convention of
>   the .mo files is based on the ISO-639 language code (e.g. pt for
>   Portuguese) followed by the ISO-3166 country code (e.g. _PT for
>   Portugal or _BR for Brazil). So, the Brazilian Portuguese file would
>   be called pt_BR.mo, and a non-specific Portuges file would be called
>   pt.mo.

Comment: if you're down voting the information I've quoted from the WordPress Codex, perhaps you could update it with more helpful info? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

After reading your answer to my comment .

To directly answer your question : any name ( e.g. `xx_XX` ) will work, and you can invent your own.

The official language codes [can be found here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_chapter/gettext_16.html#Language-Codes) ( since wordpress is using the `gettext` utility ) but Like I said, defining a language as `xx_XX` and then declaring `define ('WPLANG', 'xx_XX');` will indeed work as expected .

I have already done so in a very extreme case ( literally with `xx_XX` )

**HOWEVER :**

This is not the right way to approach the problem.

The reason is that your new translation , if applied with the standard codes ( en_US ) would be overwritten in each update , and also , you will have a hard time maintaining it .
The second reason is that it is just a bad practice .

The right way will be to filter the output, and you have a very handy filter just for that called `gettext`.

you can use it as ( for a single string ) :

```
function my_own_translation( $translated_text ) {
    if ( $translated_text == 'The old translation string' ) {
        $translated_text = 'My better translation string';
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'my_own_translation', 20 );
```

or if you have multiple

```
function my_own_translation( $translated_text ) {
    switch ( $translated_text ) {
        case 'Old translation string 1' :
            $translated_text = 'New Translation string 1';
            break;

        case 'Old translation string 2' :
            $translated_text = 'New Translation string 2';
            break;

        case 'Old translation string 3' :
            $translated_text = 'New Translation string 3';
            break;
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'my_own_translation', 20 );
```

of course , if you have many strings , array would come handy ..

```
function my_own_translation( $translated ) {
    $text = array(
        'Old translation string  1' => 'New Translation string 1',
        'Old translation string t 2' => 'New Translation string 2',
        'Old translation string  3' => 'New Translation string 3',
    );
    $translated = str_ireplace(  array_keys($text),  $text,  $translated );
    return $translated;
}
add_filter(  'gettext',  'my_own_translation', 20 );
```

Just create a plugin from that - and you are done .

**Edit I**

Reading my code after posting, and considering that we are dealing with translation, the real correct way would be :

```
$translated_text = __( 'This is my new cool translateion', 'my_domain' );
```

Also , nowdays people tend to use the most excellent [codestyling localization](http://wordpress.org/plugins/codestyling-localization/changelog), and not the poedit utility. it will make your life much easier ..

Comment: I'm not quite sure I agree with you. 1. Are you saying that using a language file to translate WordPress text strings is a bad approach (bad practice)? 2. Why do you suggest that the wp-content/language/ folder will get over written on each update?

Comment: 1 . Any changes to core files is bad practice 2. yes, If the translation file will use a standard language naming, and that language will be updated in core - your translation will be lost .

Comment: Using a language file to change text strings does not involve changing core files. You use the wordpress.pot file to generate a .mo file which contains all of your custom text strings. If WordPress updates wordpress.pot then you don't lose any of your custom text strings because they're all in your .mo file which remains untouched.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I am well familiar with the wp translation mechanisem ( after managing more than 200 multi-language sites and writing over 100 translated plugins ).I am sorry to inform you that you are wrong about this fact. the .mo and .po files DO get updated on non-english versions, and soon-to-be also on the English version ( with the new upcomming wp release ). in that respect they are considered `core` related.  you can find them in the `wp-content/Languages dir` of any non US version you will download. But do as you will - and wait to the next upgrade to see what will happen..

Comment: Take this example - I have a website written in French. I use a language file to translate all of the WordPress text strings from US English to French. WordPress then releases v3.9. Are you telling me I lose everything I've translated? Surely not?

Comment: I still think wp-content/languages does not get overwritten during upgrades. Are you able to provide a info to prove me wrong? After all - it is a content folder - why would WordPress want to overwrite content?

Comment: This is not a discussion board. Why are we [having](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18200) [this](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18960) [discussion](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18200#comment:108) ? (thats 3 links) you can just `try` for yourself and see. also, almost no one uses Poedit anymore when you have [codestyling-localization] (http://wordpress.org/plugins/codestyling-localization/changelog)